# How to trigger different emails based on different workflow conditions?

Tags: workflow

I have to set two workflow conditions 1 or 2 and i need to trigger different email alerts based on  condition 1 or condition 2.The email should be triggered only once whichever comes first(1 or 2) .How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is Not possible using Single workflow.

You have two options here.

1. Create two separate workflow and based on condition send the email.
2. Create process builder and then (based on different condition you can perform different action there)  write your logic and send the email.

I suggest you to go with Process builder so that you can decide the execution order as in case of multiple workflow we can't decide the order.